# Two FrameLayout align and tabwidget to appear at the bottom

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a layout where two FrameLayout (labelled as "mainfrg" and "aboutusdet" in the code that follows) are aligned and the tabwidget appears at the bottom.

Tabwidget appears at the bottom but the "aboutusdet" appears below "mainfrg".
    I've tried the following layout but with no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

     <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            />

     <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainfrg"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

      <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/aboutusdet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

     <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            />

</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: but what is your problem? what you gonna do?

Comment: can you share screenshot

Comment: The problem is that the FragmentLayout "aboutusdet" appears below "mainfrg". I want to align it at the right of "mainfrg" (this is for a tablet layout). Unfortunately i'm not allowed to upload an image.

Comment: At the same time, i want the tabwidget to keep appearing at the bottom of the layout